# Is spatial eigenfunction analysis a kind of direct gradient analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spatial

Everything is in the title. By eigenfunction analysis, I mean using methods based on  Moran's and asymmetrical eigenvector maps.

I have a trouble to understand if they overlap or if one is just a type of the other. Definitions I have read so far have not helped me.

Comment: What is "direct gradient analysis"?

Comment: @whuber It is (some) ecologist speak for a constrained ordination. In statistical parlance, redundancy analysis is a reduced-rank multivariate regression. Such things are often called direct gradient analysis in ecology because you model the gradients (upon which species respond) directly via a set of covariates. PCA would be an example of *indirect gradient analysis*, where the gradients (this time latent variables) are constructed without reference to a set of covariates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you mean how these are eigenfunctions relate to or explain variation in species abundances. If you just mean the process by which the eigenfunctions themselves are derived, then no, those processes are not a kind of direct gradient analysis.

The eigenfunctions are derived by some variation on the theme of

1. creating a matrix of distance between points,
2. modifying that matrix of distances via thresholding and/or other steps
3. compute the principal coordinates analysis of the modified matrix

That would be an **indirect** gradient analysis in the terminology of ecologists.

Note that all this process is doing is giving you a basis expansion of the (modified) distances between sites into a series of functions that represent different patterns of spatial-scale variation.

If you take some of those eigenfunctions and relate them to a matrix of species abundances in an RDA, CCA, or Constrained PCoA for example, then that *would* be a direct gradient analysis.